# Recommended online monitoring services with similar bare-bone scripting feature than Alertra?

Tags: monitoring, downtime, availability

I'm looking for an online service which would allow me to regularly trigger a sequence of `GET`s and `POST`s against a https website in order to mimic a simple web site navigation. The service should also allow handling of cookies.

I've registered a free trial account at **[Alertra](http://www.alertra.com)** and successfully leveraged their simple, yet efficient **[scripting language](http://www.alertra.com/articles/script_info)** to do just that.

As I'd like to be able to *choose*, I'm looking for some alternative online services with similar scripting functionality.

I've made some research but I've only found two kinds of offers

- Services that only monitor one URL at a time (not a sequence of them)
- Services that provide you with a tool to record a navigation and replay it in cloud hosted browsers (which is far too heavyweight, as I don't need to "visualize" the user interaction)

Would you know any other online service that simply leverage the HTTP protocol through script?

Comment: This question is being closed in accordance with this site's quality guidelines. Please review the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) and inquire at [meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you would like to know more about why this action was taken.